# Scrapy not yielding result (crawled 0 pages)

Tags: scrapy

Trying to figure out how scrapy works and using it to find information on forums.

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class BodybuildingItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**spider.py**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from bodybuilding.items import BodybuildingItem

class BodyBuildingSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "bodybuilding"
    allowed_domains = ["forum.bodybuilding.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://forum.bodybuilding.nl/fora/supplementen.22/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        responseSelector = Selector(response)
        for sel in responseSelector.css('li.past.line.event-item'):
            item = BodybuildingItem()
            item['title'] = sel.css('a.data-previewUrl::text').extract()
            yield item
```

The forum I'm trying to get the post titles from in this example is this: https://forum.bodybuilding.nl/fora/supplementen.22/

However I keep getting no results:

> class BodyBuildingSpider(BaseSpider): 2017-10-07 00:42:28
>   [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: bodybuilding)
>   2017-10-07 00:42:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings:
>   {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bodybuilding.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':
>   ['bodybuilding.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME':
>   'bodybuilding'} 2017-10-07 00:42:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled
>   extensions: ['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats'] 2017-10-07 00:42:28
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2017-10-07
>   00:42:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2017-10-07 00:42:28
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2017-10-07
>   00:42:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2017-10-07 00:42:28
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2017-10-07 00:42:28
>   [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) https://forum.bodybuilding.nl/robots.txt> (referer: None) 2017-10-07
>   00:42:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://forum.bodybuilding.nl/fora/supplementen.22/> (referer: None)
>   2017-10-07 00:42:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
>   (finished) 2017-10-07 00:42:29 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping
>   Scrapy stats: {'downloader/request_bytes': 469, 
>   'downloader/request_count': 2,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET':
>   2,  'downloader/response_bytes': 22878,  'downloader/response_count':
>   2,  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,  'finish_reason':
>   'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 6, 22, 42, 29,
>   223305),  'log_count/DEBUG': 2,  'log_count/INFO': 7,  'memusage/max':
>   31735808,  'memusage/startup': 31735808,  'response_received_count':
>   2,  'scheduler/dequeued': 1,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1, 
>   'scheduler/enqueued': 1,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1, 
>   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 6, 22, 42, 28, 816043)}
>   2017-10-07 00:42:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed
>   (finished)

I have been following the guide here: http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/07/scrapy-and-elasticsearch.html

**Update 1:**

As someone told me I needed to update my code to the new standards, which I did but it didnt change the outcome:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from bodybuilding.items import BodybuildingItem

class BodyBuildingSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "bodybuilding"
    allowed_domains = ["forum.bodybuilding.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://forum.bodybuilding.nl/fora/supplementen.22/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.css('li.past.line.event-item'):
            item = BodybuildingItem()
            yield {'title': title.css('a.data-previewUrl::text').extract_first()}
            yield item
```

**Last update with fix**

After some good help I finally got it working with this spider:

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bodybuilding'
    start_urls = ['https://forum.bodybuilding.nl/fora/supplementen.22/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('h3.title'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a::text').extract_first()}
            next_page_url = response.xpath("//a[text()='Volgende >']/@href").extract_first()
            if next_page_url:
                 yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: You should use `response.css('li.past.line.event-item')` and there is no need for `responseSelector = Selector(response)`. Also the CSS you are using are no more valid, so you need update those first based on the latest web page

Comment: I think i've updated it all now, still nothing. See update.

Comment: The problem is there is nothing on page which matches `li.past.line.event-item`

Comment: Yeah just got it working, i finally figured that part out. However, the last thing I need is for it to be able to follow the "next" button.. If I look at the source it the div where the button is in is called "PageNav" but the actual next button doesnt have a own div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `response.css('li.past.line.event-item')` and there is no need for `responseSelector = Selector(response)`.

Also the CSS you are using `li.past.line.event-item`, is no more valid, so you need update those first based on the latest web page

To get the next page URL you can use

```
>>> response.css("a.text::attr(href)").extract_first()
'fora/supplementen.22/page-2'
```

And then use `response.follow` to follow this relative url

**Edit-2: Next Page processing correction**

The previous edit didn't work because on the next page it matches the previous page url, so you need to use below

```
next_page_url = response.xpath("//a[text()='Volgende >']/@href").extract_first()
if next_page_url:
   yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

**Edit-1: Next Page processing**

```
next_page_url = response.css("a.text::attr(href)").extract_first()
if next_page_url:
   yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: this is what it looks like now:

for next_page in response.css("a.text::attr(href)").extract_first():
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)

but getting an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".
Which tells me line 11 has an issue, which is the for loop i just showed.

Comment: hmm something weird happens when I add that.. it first does the first page, then the 2nd and then the first again but it never jumps further then page 2.

Comment: Check Edit -2 please

Comment: Oh wow yes that works perfectly. Could you explain to me how the line "("//a[text()='Volgende >']/@href")" works? It seems way more effectives than css.

Comment: `"//a[text()='Volgende >']` find link anywhere with the text  `'Volgende >'` and the `/@href` to get it's href

Comment: Ah I understand.. seems really effective. Thank you for all your help sir! Appreciated very much! I will show me full spider code now in the first post as an update.